# How to center the logo Description in Protostar Joomla 3.4

Tags: templates, css

The phrase description under the logo. I want to center that. For now I had to put a line under for spacing. If I go to the template settings (`Template manager -> Styles -> Protostar -> Advanced`), centering it in Joomla admin is not an option.

It looks like this:

> My Logo is Here
>   The phrase

*needs to be*

> My Logo is Here
>      The phrase

so I went to 
I tried going to 
`public_html/templates/protostar/index.php`   ...line 141 and added a space (`&nbsp;`) but it didn't work:

```
<?php if ($this->params->get('&nbsp;&nbsp;sitedescription')) : ?>
<?php echo '<div class="site-description">' . htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('&nbsp;&nbsp;sitedescription')) . '</div>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

---

Actually I just figured it out...
Put the style with the amount of px you need your description to go to the left. See where I added `style="margin-left: 10px;"`

```
<a class="brand pull-left" href="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>/">
  <?php echo $logo; ?>
  <?php if ($this->params->get('sitedescription')) : ?>
  <?php echo '<div class="site-description" style="margin-left: 10px;">' . htmlspecialchars($this->params->get('sitedescription')) . '</div>'; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to do it would be to add the following css to /templates/protostar/css/template.css (or, if you will recompile the LESS then /templates/protostar/less/template.less):

```
.site-description {text-align: center;}
```

Comment: Even better since Joomla 3.5.0, create a custom CSS file at /templates/protostar/css/user.css which will be loaded automatically and won't be overwritten by future updates to the template.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to use

`.header-inner .site-title, 
.header-inner .site-description {
    text-align: center;
}`

As it would allow you avoid both situations:

1. Title is bigger than description
2. Title is smaller than description

Answer (score 0):

Which place you want to display the description using this css templates/protostar/css/template.css

```
.site-description 
{
    margin:0 22px !important ;
}
```